# BaseAdapter returns wrong position on getView() method call

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

Strangely enough my `CustomBaseAdapter` is returning wrong position for the item that needs to be inflated and so on the adapter takes the wrong kind of data to display on the row!

Although i am using the `ViewHolder` pattern, my ListView `layout_height` is set to `match_parent` and every possible way i have found, to ensure ListView items stability, is already implemented, the `CustomBaseAdapter` seems not to be responding at it.

**getView() method**

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        mItemView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //setting up the Views
            mItemView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) mItemView.getTag();
        }

        //Getting the item
        final MyItem item = getItem(position);

        //Doing some checks on my item and then display the appropriate data.

        //By saying checks i mean something like: 

        if(item.getSomething().equals("blabla")){
           //Load some pic
        }else{
           //Load another pic
        }
        //Now when i have scrolled the list once and return back to top,
        //Suddenly in Logcat i am seeing that the first row is getting matched to
        //the object in the 4th position, but it doesnt display its data. It displays
        //the text from the first item as it was supposed to do. But the relation between
        //the first row and the item's position is like 0->4. 
}
```

**Other methods**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mObjects.size();
}

@Override
public MyItem getItem(int position) {
    return this.mObjects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

I have literally searched and tried everything on Google! Nothing seems to have given me a solution.

Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if you need any more part of code.

Comment: take a look here ... yeah i know it is 1h but, worth it ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: I have already watched it but couldn't understand what i am doing wrong!

Comment: Yeah i fixed that, but giving -1 just because you are guessing that i may be doing some kind of silly check is not that fair. Anyway...

Comment: @Selvin hmmm maybe you are getting the rules wrong! I have already put the minimum code needed to explain my issue! I am not seeking for any kind of debugging help. After 3 years of developing in Android i can easily debug myself! I just felt into this issue today and couldn't explain it after lots of hours searching and trying! That's why i thought of asking in SO. If you are not in the mood of helping then just dont. Simple as that!

Comment: i'm in pretty good mood and i'm willing to help you but you seems do not like to accept it ... for FSM sake what means `Suddenly in Logcat i am seeing that the first row is getting matched` hmmm does logcat shows some log without your code? that's strange ... what do you mean by `matched` (what you are comparing?) what do you mean by `display` (display where? what? how?)

Comment: I am logging the item's data and the position and they do not seem to match! Is that so hard for you to understand ???

Comment: check the edit in prev comment ... is that so hard for you to understand that **without code** it is not obviouse what you are doing there? *i wrote some code and it is not working as it should, how can i fix it?* <= sounds familiar? ... why are you using final?  are you using inner in-place interface/class  implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `mItemView` is the culprit here. Judging by the name, this is an instance field,  so if more than one thread calls `getView()` in your `CustomBaseAdapter`, then `mItemView` may change which recycled view it is pointing at right under your nose. Also, I assume that `getView()` ends with a `return mItemView`, right?

Anyway, I would advise to try eliminating `mItemView` and just write the function like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        //setting up the Views
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    // ...

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: "Also, I assume that getView() ends with a return mItemView, right?" That kinda saved me a lot of time and this pattern strangely works again without redraws + some other modifications i did when loading the adapter! I am accepting the answer and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are "recycling" the display objects, but you are responsible for getting the proper data into them. The issue is this line of code:

```
    mItemView = convertView;
```

`convertView` is the "container" for your data. If `convertView` is not null, then the container is constructed, but you must then put the appropriate data into it. This is typically done by "using" the position indicator.

Maybe like this:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        mItemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //setting up the Views
        mItemView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = getItem(position);
        mItemView.setTag(holder);
    }
```

Comment: Why would i make the holder equal to the item in the selected position? Can you explain the purpose of holder = getItem(position);

Comment: @Selvin: What is your point? And how am i supposed to pass the right data if an item is reused?

Comment: i meant: this code has no sens but the first part about recycling is true

Comment: Yes but how am i supposed to rearrange the relations between rows and objects?